# Comment style for license headers in Java

Tags: java, licensing

It is recommended to add a license-header to the top of each file that includes Copyright and licensing informations (e.g. GPL3 suggests adding [this](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-howto.en.html)). Is there a standard comment-style to use for the license header in Java or can I use whatever I like?

I know that the [License Maven Plugin](http://code.mycila.com/license-maven-plugin/) suggest using Javadoc-styled comments and this is what I am using right now, but recently discovered that [some projects](https://github.com/SpongePowered/SpongeAPI/commit/c744deead0b0925ea22e6dbe02cdb0fa5a5b4f17) use simple multi line commends (just a single `*`) instead. Will Javadoc-like comments produce problems when using the Javadoc tool?

Comment: I edited the question to clarify what information I was asking for. In this form it is, as I believe, definitely not opinion-based. Rather an answer like "use whatever you like" would be valid and helpfull (as is the accepted answer).

Comment: The problem is that "use whatever you like" or "use xyz" is an opinion-based answer ... as is just about any other answer.  The only factual answer is that there is no **Standard** for this ... in the sense of a standard that has been ratified by a standards body.

Comment: @StephenC That was what I meant. I asked if there was a standard way to do this - knowing there is now standard answers _my_ original questions. Sorry if my first comment was confusing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `/* */`, it seems to be the standard in the majority of open source java projects. Javadoc should be used to describe Java classes, interfaces, constructors, methods, and fields.

However, if you want to use a Javadoc I guess you can, and it will not get on your way if you put an import statement just after it. According to [this documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#comments) on placement of comments:

> A common mistake is to put an import statement between the class comment and the class declaration. Avoid this, as the Javadoc tool will ignore the class comment.

```
/**
* This is the class comment for the class Whatever.
*/

import com.sun;   // MISTAKE - Important not to put import statement here

public class Whatever {
}
```

Comment: Note that `com.mycila:license-maven-plugin` can be configured to use `/* */` style comments : `<configuration><mapping><java>SLASHSTAR_STYLE</java></mapping></configuration>`